# How to update text, when clicking on image

Tags: javascript, html, image, addeventlistener

I want to update score, when clicking on the image, but it just wont happen.

i have the HTML:

```
<img id="item1" src="http://nikolajlicht.com/Unicorn/lasso.png">
<h1 id="score"></h1>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var score = 100;
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');

var scoreText = document.getElementById('score');
scoreText.innerText = score;

item1.addEventlistener('click',function(){
    score -= 20;
    scoreText.innerText = score;
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `addEventListener` vs `addEventlistener` in your code.

Comment: A little googling or revising your code thoroughly  could have solved your problem easily. I don't see any need for posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
item1.addEventListener('click',function(){
```

with an **uppercase L**.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mm2j481t/

Answer (score 0):

item1.addEvent**L**istener instead yours item1.addEventlistener